# USB Programming: C/Linux

Tags: c, linux, usb

What are the best tutorials and API's for Linux and C based USB programming? I want to be able to transfer data at max throughput point to point between two PCs, with USB 3.0.

Comment: You should accept some answers for your previous questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the Ethernet over Usb kernel driver (a howto for setting up one machine is [here](http://www.ruault.com/Zaurus/ethernet-over-usb-howto.html)), set up static IPs on both ends, and use `rcp`.

Comment: There is the overhead of Ethernet frames with this approach, which will limit throughput. Any ideas by how much? In fact even worse if its IP over Ethernet.

Answer (score 2):

You can't connect two Hosts directly over USB, one side must have a device controller (such as the NetChip 228x), in which case you can load the `g_ether` module (enabled with `USB_ETH`) and do as suggested by [gnud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170163/usb-programming-c-linux/5170328#5170328)